# Spring Boot 2.5 with Keycloak: Inconsistent Logout Behavior Across Multiple Applications

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, keycloak

I have three applications (A, B, and C) integrated with the same Keycloak realm, each having different clients. They all use their backend as a resource (not a client), and Vue.js on the frontend acts as the client.

- **Application A:**

  - Backend: Spring Boot 1.5
  - Frontend: Vue.js
- **Application B:**

  - Backend: Spring Boot 2.5 (recently upgraded)
  - Frontend: Vue.js
- **Application C:**

  - Backend: Spring Boot 1.5
  - Frontend: Vue.js

#### Issue:

When I logout from Application A, I still remain logged in on Application B, which does not return a 401 on various calls even though I am logged out. However, I am correctly logged out from Application C. On the other hand, if I logout from Application B, I am also logged out from Applications A and C and receive a 401 from the backend. This issue seems to have appeared after upgrading Application B to Spring Boot 2.5.

#### Configuration of Application B:

**Properties File:**

```
# Context of the application
server.contextPath=/appli-squelette

# Keycloak Information
keycloak.url= [KEYCLOAK_URL]
keycloak.protocol=openid-connect
keycloak.redirect_uri=[REDIRECT_URI]
keycloak.client.id=[CLIENT_ID]
keycloak.scope=openid profile

# JWT Security Configuration
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=${keycloak.url}
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.jwk-set-uri=${keycloak.url}/protocol/openid-connect/certs

# Other security properties
security.oauth2.resource.preferTokenInfo=false
security.basic.enabled=false
```

#### OAuth2AuthenticationConfiguration.java:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true)
public class OAuth2AuthenticationConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${keycloak.client.id}")
    private String clientId;

    @Bean
    public RequestMatcher resources() {
        return AnyRequestMatcher.INSTANCE;
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestContextListener requestContextListener() {
        return new RequestContextListener();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        JwtAuthenticationConverter jwtAuthenticationConverter = new JwtAuthenticationConverter();
        jwtAuthenticationConverter.setJwtGrantedAuthoritiesConverter(new GrantedAuthoritiesExtractor(clientId));

        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/rest/version",
                        "/rest/constantes/**",
                        "/rest/swagger-ui.html"
                ).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/rest/**").authenticated()
                .and()
                .logout().permitAll().logoutSuccessUrl("/")
                .and()
                .oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                .jwtAuthenticationConverter(jwtAuthenticationConverter);
    }
}
```

#### Question:

Has anyone encountered a similar issue, particularly after upgrading to Spring Boot 2.5? Is there any configuration that I might be missing or that needs to be updated to ensure consistent logout behavior across all applications?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated!